# Netherite Armor to Elytra

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I’m trying to make an elytra in Minecraft that is equal to a full set of netherite armor. My dilema is that I’m having trouble doing the math to calculate the level of protection that would be equal to a full set of netherite armor (protection 4 enchants included). If it makes the calculations any easier, the percentage of damage reduction of a full set of netherite armor is about 86%.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You mean combining 4 pieces of full-enchanted Netherite armor to create an enchanted Elytra?

Comment: No, i mean having an elytra that when worn is equal to the protection of a full set of netherite armor

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of this is? This is so I can refine my expectations of your intended goal before I answer.

Comment: I have a role play minecraft server where seeing a players skin is important. I want to be able to have netherite armor without actually wearing the entire set. I want it to just be on the elytra

Comment: did the answer below help?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use **attributes** to give elytra, when worn, the same stats as netherite armor, including armor points, knockback resistance, and toughness. I am not sure if protection works with elytra.

Applying this can either be done with a give command (something to the effect of):

```
/give @p elytra{AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Amount:8,Slot:chest,Name:"generic.armor",UUID:[I;-12301,33526,23730,-67052]},{AttributeName:"generic.armor_toughness",Amount:3,Slot:chest,Name:"generic.armor_toughness",UUID:[I;-12301,33626,23730,-67252]},{AttributeName:"generic.knockback_resistance",Amount:0.1,Slot:chest,Name:"generic.knockback_resistance",UUID:[I;-12301,33726,23730,-67452]}]}
```

for which I have found this site helpful: https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/give-command-generator
(Note that, unlike on netherite armor, this seems to put KB resistance before toughness for some reason, despite being a smaller number)

or... a complicated datapack to test and `/item modify` it when worn